# Replacing all occurrences of alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace all alphanumeric characters in my string with the character "-" using regex. So if the input is "Dune" i should get "----". currently though I'm getting just the single "-";

```
string s = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(s);
string s = "dune";
string result = rgx.Replace(s, "-");

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.Read();
```

right now i know its looking for the string "dune" rather then the letters "d" "u" "n" "e". but i can find another class that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is too greedy, remove the * and start end string matches. It should be

```
string s = "[a-zA-Z0-9]";
```

This will then only match 1 character anywhere in the string rather than all. You could also look at the shorthand for any alphanumeric

```
String s= "\w";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string s = "[a-zA-Z0-9]";
Regex rgx = new Regex(s);
string s = "dune";
string result = rgx.Replace(s, "-");

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Beat me too it, should add an explanation for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have one **String** `s` for your regular expression and another **String** `s` for your string? I would change this to eliminate *confusion/error* here.

Also to replace **each** alphanumeric character, you need to remove the beginning of string/end of string anchors `^ $` and the `*` quantifier meaning (`0` or more times, matching the *most* amount possible)

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
string s  = "dune";
string result = rgx.Replace(s, "-");
Console.WriteLine(result); //=> "----"
```